# how to give a non-zero value a larger weight with loss function in a regression task?

Tags: python, tensorflow, statistics

I have a regression task: y = f(x),
most of values in y is zero, thus, if using mean square error (mse) as loss function, the model will give all predicted y as very small values;
So, I want to give larger weight to the non-zero values in y;
What should I do?
One solution I want to try is define a new loss function:

> loss = e * mse(y, y_pred)[y!=0] + (1-e) * mse(y, y_pred)[y==0]

e is the weight parameter, will it work? How to implement in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

if you want just larger values in your y tensor you can multiply your y tensor with a scalar variable

```
y=tf.math.multiply(y,10)
```

some cases models trained with mse predict very smooth outputs if you want sharper outputs you can use mean_pairwise_squared_error

```
loss=tf.losses.mean_pairwise_squared_error(y_pred,y,weights=e)
```